# Last line of a file is not reading in shell script

Tags: shell, file

I have a text file `foo.txt` with the below text as content,

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I have a shell script,

```
file="foo.txt" 
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

But this prints only till `4`.

**Actual Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

How to get the expected output as below?

**Expected Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to missing line break in the last line of your input file.

You can use this loop to read everything:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

For the last line without line break, `read` doesn't return a success hence `[ -n "$line" ]` check is done to make sure to print it when `$line` is not empty.

PS: If you don't mind changing your input file then use `printf` to append a newline using:

```
printf '\n' >> "$file"
```

And then read normally:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: I included a line break in the input file and it worked

Comment: If I understand this right, the addition of the line break is cumulative?  So if you run this script several times, you'll end up with a bunch of line breaks at the end of the file.

Comment: Yes that's right @Daggar